# How to get Jenkin's Add Maven option under Configure System

Tags: maven, jenkins, missing-features

I've got what seems like a very basic question. I'm following a tutorial.  It says to install Maven via **Manager Jenkins - Configure System - Add Maven**.

This works great on Windows. But on MAC **Add Maven** is missing. Even after I install a fresh copy of Jenkins 2.2

How can I resolve this?

The following "Add XXX" are missing on MAC under Configure System.

[image]

Comment: Happened in Windows as well(Browser : Google Chrome).

Comment: Correct - my problem was the version of Jenkins I'd installed on Mac versus Windows

Comment: Yes you have mentioned it clearly in your question. My point is that this error can occur in Windows platform as well. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you checked "Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration" yet? I think those settings (including JDK, Maven, Ant...) are moved from "Configure System" to another place.

Comment: Bingo. It was that simple. Suppose it makes sense as Configure System was getting too verbose. Thanks for that.

Comment: In German "Global Tool Configuration" is called "Konfiguration der Hilfsprogramme".

Comment: super, helps me